# 16-bit ALU always results in 0

Tags: verilog

```
always @* begin
if (SEL == 3'b000)
    ALU_OUT = A + B;
if (SEL == 3'b001)
    ALU_OUT = A - B;
if (SEL == 3'b010)
    ALU_OUT = ~(A & B);
if (SEL == 3'b011);
    ALU_OUT = ~(A | B);
if (SEL == 3'b100)
    ALU_OUT = ~A;
if (SEL == 3'b101)
    ALU_OUT = A >> B;
else 
    ALU_OUT = 0;
end
```

The above is my code, currently for the ALU. I have to code for overflow, but the main problem is that nothing in the code works. I am not sure what I have to fix because the computer doesn't say there is any errors. But, I fail all the tests.  All the results are 0.

Comment: the operations are only defined for 6 out of 8 combinations which is why i put ALU_OUT = 0 for else

Comment: there is a given test bench code, and so all i have to do is create a code for ALU. when i compile testbench and my code together and run it, I have passed 0 tests as in the code gave incorrect output, although it runs normally( There is no syntax error).

Comment: i am not an expert  but you can try  replacing  ALU_OUT =  with  ALU_OUT <=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a logic mistake.  You have 5 separate `if` statements, plus 1 `if/else` statement.  You most likely meant to have a single cascading `if/else if/ else` statement.  In order to avoid this type of a mistake, it is better to use a `case` statement:

```
always @* begin
    case (SEL)
        3'b000  : ALU_OUT = A + B;
        3'b001  : ALU_OUT = A - B;
        3'b010  : ALU_OUT = ~(A & B);
        3'b011  : ALU_OUT = ~(A | B);
        3'b100  : ALU_OUT = ~A;
        3'b101  : ALU_OUT = A >> B;
        default : ALU_OUT = 0;
    endcase
end
```

With the `case` statement, once `SEL` matches one of the case items, the `case` statement is exited immediately.

In your code, each `if` is evaluated, and the last one wins.  For example, if `SEL` is 0, then `ALU_OUT = A + B` is executed.  The simulator, also checks the remaining `if` statements.  When it reaches `if (SEL == 3'b101)`, that evaluates to false, which means the `else` statement is executed: `ALU_OUT = 0`.  This is why you get 0.  The `else` is executed for any value of `SEL`.

I posted a complete testbench on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/TA9d) demonstrating that the `case` statement works.